# downgrading to iOS 4

Tags: ios, ios4

I am reading "Head first iPhone and iPad development". Its for iOS 4. A lot seems to have changed with iOS 5 making it difficult to follow the book and I am not keen to change the book. I am using Xcode 4.3.2 on Mac OS 10.7. How can I use Xcode with iOS 4 instead of iOS 5?

Comment: Change the book. Don't learn iOS 4 when iOS 7 is due to be out in a month or two. A lot has changed since then. If you're serious about learning to program for iOS you'll need to have a mac and an iOS device. Compared to those the cost of a new book is pretty small.

Comment: I do have a MacBook Air and iPhone 3GS. The reason for not changing the book is not cost. Its the style and approach of the book. But I am keen to know which book would you recommend for newbies.

Comment: I don't know which book to recommend but I don't believe that the choice of which OS to develop for is best made according to the writing style of one book. Best close this question and go read some reviews on Amazon.

Comment: You'll have a much bigger cost hit when no one buys your app because it only supports an ancient iOS version

Comment: You can still use the mechanisms designed for iOS4, but you are better off learning from a newer source. The Stanford iOS course on iTunes U is a really good course to take that will probably give you a lot more than most beginner books if you follow it properly.

Comment: Given the vast majority of users are on iOS 6 and iOS 7 will be out soon, learning anything older than iOS 6 is pointless. You need to keep current with iOS development. It won't be long before Apple won't accept apps that support iOS 4.3 and probably not too long (a year?) before they stop accepting apps that support iOS 5.